# mysql: finding the shortest and the longest value within an mysql-column

Tags: mysql, indexing, substring, find-in-set

I had a question about finding the shortest und the longest value within an concated string in MySQL-Column "values" .
The Problem, the values within the column are concated with "|" and may be diffrent long.

Table:

```
ID  |  values 
----------------------------------------
A   |  12.1|11.23|134.44
B   |  11.134|1.3|34.5|152.12|1.31313|134.331|12.31
C   |  34.11|1.34|343412.2|13......
```

The question is: Is there some simple possiblity to find both (shortest and the longest) value only by native mysql query, without using any language as Java or PHP.

Thank you

Comment: Fix your data structure to have a table with a separate row for each value and one value.

Comment: This isn't a valid data set within the framework of an RDBMS

Comment: What does these values represents? Please add the expected output.

Comment: I know that this table structure does not represent the modern view of data storage, but there are no opportunity to change the data structrure, we have to handle the legacy code and structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the result you need in a single query, at least not in the current version of MySQL. The reason is that you can't form a query to fetch individual elements from a delimited string of unknown length before you know the maximum length.

First find out how many elements are in the longest list:

```
select max(length(`values`)-length(replace(`values`, '|', ''))) as max from t;
+------+
| max  |
+------+
|    6 |
+------+
```

Now you know you'll need to test up to 7 "fields" within your delimited string. There's no way to form SQL with a variable number of unioned queries. The syntax must be fixed at prepare time, so you need to know how many.

```
select id, substring_index(substring_index(`values`, '|', 1), '|', -1) as element from t
union
select id, substring_index(substring_index(`values`, '|', 2), '|', -1) from t
union
select id, substring_index(substring_index(`values`, '|', 3), '|', -1) from t
union
select id, substring_index(substring_index(`values`, '|', 4), '|', -1) from t
union
select id, substring_index(substring_index(`values`, '|', 5), '|', -1) from t
union
select id, substring_index(substring_index(`values`, '|', 6), '|', -1) from t
union
select id, substring_index(substring_index(`values`, '|', 7), '|', -1) from t;    

+------+----------+
| id   | element  |
+------+----------+
| A    | 12.1     |
| A    | 11.23    |
| A    | 134.44   |
| B    | 11.134   |
| B    | 1.3      |
| B    | 34.5     |
| B    | 152.12   |
| B    | 1.31313  |
| B    | 134.331  |
| B    | 12.31    |
| C    | 34.11    |
| C    | 1.34     |
| C    | 343412.2 |
| C    | 13       |
+------+----------+
```

Now use the query above as a subquery, you can find the longest or shortest:

```
(select id, element from (...subquery...) as t1 order by length(element) asc limit 1)
union
(select id, element from (...subquery...) as t2 order by length(element) desc limit 1)

+------+----------+
| id   | element  |
+------+----------+
| C    | 343412.2 |
| C    | 13       |
+------+----------+
```

I agree with others who have commented that this is really the wrong way to use an RDBMS. I understand you said that you're committed to this structure, but you'll find in the long run, it makes more work for you than the work it would take to fix the schema.

See also my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: Thank You! That's the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Max Length

```
select * from table order by length(column_name) DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Min Length

```
select * from table order by length(column_name) ASC LIMIT 0,1
```

If this is not what you looking add your SQL query into the question.

Comment: i am looking for the shortes/longest value within the string, not the string-lenght itself. for example the value in second row, 1.3 would be the shortest value....

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not friendly to arrays of values in cells.  Restructure the schema; then the solution will be easy.